# Module analogue of the following dimension result

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

There is a result for the following exact sequence of finite dimensional vector spaces (over a field):

Given an exact sequence:
$$W_2\xrightarrow{\phi_2}W_1\xrightarrow{\phi_1}W_0\xrightarrow{\phi_0}W_{-1}\xrightarrow{\phi_{-1}}W_{-2},$$
we have $$\dim(W_0)=\dim(W_1)-\dim(\text{Im}(\phi_2))+\dim(W_{-1})-\dim(\text{Im}(\phi_{-1})).$$

> Is there any analogue of this result for ranks of $R$-modules, $R$ a commutative ring? The $R$-modules may or may not be free. It is ok if it is an inequality rather than an equality.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There should be an evident connection between how the rank-nullity theorem treats dimensions of vector spaces and the first isomorphism theorem...

Comment: What do you mean by "rank" if the modules are not free?

Comment: @EricWofsey I mean the rank of the free part

Comment: What do you mean by "the free part"?

Comment: @EricWofsey I mean the cardinality of a maximal linearly independent subset of the module. Is there such a thing? For "nice" modules?